# Set state based on other objects in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to learn ReactJS by building a personal launch page. Sloppy explanation ahead.

Inside my main app.js file, I've initialized the state of the app with some info like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      links: {
        listA: ["CodeCademy","Udemy","StackOverflow","This is list A"],
        listB: ["ADSR","Youtube","Reddit", "This is list B"],
        listC: ["Overwatch", "R6S", "CSGO", "This is list C"],
        listD: ["Soundcloud", "Pandora", "Spotify", "This is list D"]
      },
      linkbar: {
        links1: "coding",
        links2: "chillin",
        links3: "vidya",
        links4: "music"
      },
      //activeList : something
    }; //etc
```

But for the life of me, I can't figure out if there's a way to base a property off of an existing property. In this case, I want to swap out the lists by referencing an `activeList` pair that references one of the `this.state.links` arrays. Any time I try to reference the arrays, however, results in an error saying activeList is undefined.

Am I missing something here? Is there a different way to approach this via a method that would do this appropriately? Is it possible to define activeList within the state or does this need to be done outside via a const? Appreciate any guidance, learning React is a bit rough for me here. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please specify what is "undefined" in the error? Is the state undefined or is the activeList undefined?

Comment: Apologies, activeList is undefined if I try to define it as links.listA, this.state.links.listA, etc. Not sure if this is the appropriate way to reference this.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand how(or where) you are trying to reference the activeList. Can you please add some more code to you example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to interact with multiple levels inside the state, is to manipulate your objects outside the state then pass them in.

From what I see of your code, I'm not sure that playing with states for all this is the best idea. However here is an example.

```
myHandler() {
    var levelA = {...this.state.levelA};
    levelA.levelB = ["hello"];
    // so something
    this.setState(levelA);
}
```

Comment: @IkeDoud, I wrote this from my phone I hope I did not make mistakes, but that's the idea

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - thanks a ton for the help! switching the handler with componentWillMount got me set up for the init perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome, I've also been searching quite a lot on this in the past!